# Do Network Services support Multimodal Networks (ArcGIS 10.1, Network Analyst Extension)?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, network-analyst, multimodal-network

Do Network Services support Multimodal Networks (ArcGIS 10.1)?

I'm assuming that multimodal networks are supported, but I am troubleshooting and just want to be sure.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Network Services (map services published with the Network Analysis capability on) support multi-modal networks. I am able to perform routing on a such service published locally from a simple JS application.